# How to find r2score of my PyTorch model for regression

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have a UNet model. I'm trying for a regression model since, in my output, I have different floating values for each pixel. In order to check the r2score, I tried to put the below code in the `model class`, training_step, validation_step, and test_step.

`from pytorch_lightning.metrics.functional import r2score`

`r2 = r2score(pred, y)`

`self.log('r2:',r2)`

But it's giving the following error

> ValueError: Expected both prediction and target to be 1D or 2D tensors, but recevied tensors with dimension torch.Size([50, 1, 32, 32])

How can I check my model fit?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the function accepts 1D or 2D tensors, but your tensor is 4D (B x C x H x W). So to use the function you should reshape it:

```
r2 = r2score(pred.view(pred.shape[1], -1), y.view(y.shape[1], -1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now getting a new error `ValueError: Needs atleast two samples to calculate r2 score.`

Comment: Changed the code to `r2 = r2score(pred.view(-1), y.view(-1))` now it's working. Thanks